# What is the word for this container?

Tags: terminology, image-identification

It's glazed ceramic, tan and brown.  There's no handle.  It's about 21" tall and about 10" diameter.  It's quite heavy.  The sides are straight up and down.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: *Jug* is the most generic term, though *carboy* is probably better for one of that size.  And there are several other terms that don't come to mind just now.  (I would guess that this one was made for the manufacture of wine or some other fermented beverage, and there may be term in the brewer's craft for it.)

Comment: What does it contain?

Comment: *stoneware jug* returns images very similar to the one you depict...

Comment: Also *crock jug*...

Comment: I was thinking "jug" but wasn't sure, since it doesn't have a handle.  I looked for similar listings on ebay, but "jug" only turned up smaller 1-gallon-ish sized containers.  I guess I'll call it a jug in my listing and see what happens!  @NVZ it's been empty since I've owned it - almost 20 years.  I have no idea what it originally held.

Comment: British Rum Jar http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/30028460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be an English rum jar. Often labeled with SRD (Supply Reserve Depot), these jars historically held rum for British soldiers fighting in wars. You can learn more about them [here](https://pointsadhsblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/world-war-i-part-2-the-british-rum-ration/).

[image]

Comment: Such jugs were used to hold many different substances.  I've seen them in rural areas of the US that never had any English rum within 500 miles.

Comment: @HotLicks: 'Cause it was all drunk up!

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a jug although they often have a handle you can put one finger through.  Generally they're stoppered with a cork.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a [carboy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carboy) :  a large container, sometimes in a frame for support, used for storing and transporting liquids:

A large carboy will protect wine from a fairly large temperature swing.

(Definition of carboy from the Cambridge Business English Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)

Also a demijohn.

No sense not getting in deeper: [[National Directory of Commodity Specifications: Classified and Alphabetical Lists and Brief Descriptions of Specifications of National Recognition, 1945](https://books.google.ca/books?id=v8mwoTvnA48C&pg=PA1124&lpg=PA1124&dq=earthenware%20carboy%20manufacturer&source=bl&ots=Uu_uMQa4SA&sig=B8zv5oozM05mKthe0SC7MjFZlxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwlPb54_DMAhULTlIKHRh7CJgQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=earthenware%20carboy%20manufacturer&f=false)  (US regulations)

> ...Storage of Acids US Gov Interstate Commerce Commission Regulations
>   for Transportation of Explosives and Other Dangerous Articles *Shipping
>   Container Specification 1A* **Boxed Carboys Glass Earthenware Clay or
>   Stoneware** *Specification IB* **Boxed Lead Carboys** *Specification 1C* **Carboys II in Kegs Glass Earthenware Clay or Stoneware** Includes requirements for
>   manufacture of carboys outside containers and tests Published by
>   American Trucking Assns Inc Tariff Bureau and Assn of American
>   Railroads Bureau of Explosives US Gov Interstate Commerce Commission
>   Regulations for Transportation of Explosives and Other Dangerous
>   Articles *Shipping Container Specification IX* **Boxed Carboys 5 to 6
>   Gallons for Export Only Glass Earthenware Clay or Stoneware** Single
>   Trip Container Includes requirements for manufacture marking and tests
>   Published by American Trucking Assns Inc Tariff Bureau and by Assn
>   American Railroads Bureau of Explosives

Comment: I believe that carboy is made of glass.

Comment: @Matsmath - Not necessarily.

Comment: @HotLicks On a second thought, I reconcile: I should have said that *I believe that carboys are never made of ceramic*. Proof: [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=carboy&client=ubuntu&hs=czG&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyn9zz4fDMAhVmDJoKHUj4CoIQ_AUICCgC&biw=1535&bih=803)

Comment: @Matsmath https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&biw=1122&bih=582&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=carboy+ceramic&oq=carboy+ceramic&gs_l=img.3...45768.49792.0.50191.12.10.2.0.0.0.119.1008.4j6.10.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.6.436...0j0i10i24.y314GsHCVOc

Comment: Yeah, *demijohn* is one that I knew was out there but couldn't think of.

Comment: @HotLicks All right. I especially like [this one](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Isl%2Be5vHL._SX355_.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

It could be a [canopic jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopic_jar).

> Canopic jars were used by the ancient Egyptians during the
>   mummification process to store and preserve the viscera of their owner
>   for the afterlife. They were commonly either carved from limestone or were made of pottery.

From [Oxford English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/canopic-jar):

> A covered urn used in ancient Egyptian burials to hold the entrails from an embalmed body.

Comment: Canopic jars are lidded.  This vessel does not appear to have a lid. (BTW, not my downvote)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Indeed, I just wanted to comment that a [baboon head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapi_%28Son_of_Horus%29) could have made the picture more authentic. Well... can you clarify your comment? I think that the brown top is actually a (rather large) lid.

Comment: It is my downvote, since there's no way the pictured jug was designed as a burial urn of any sort.

Comment: If you'd ever seen one of these in the flesh you'd know that the brown top is simply a different color glaze on the ceramic.  It's traditional to make them two-toned, with the brown/white combo shown by far the most common.  The opening to the jug is in the neck at the very top of the picture.

Comment: Oh, the imperfect painting made me think otherwise. That's why I suggested canopic jar in the first place. Rats. As a side note, your reasoning as *no way the pictured jug was designed as a burial urn* lacks any solid reasoning. You say this, based on what?

Comment: Based on the point that you could hardly fit any part of a body through the roughly 1.5" spout opening, plus one would expect that a vessel intended for burying someone would be *a little* more ornate and respectful in appearance.

Comment: @ab2 - What writing?

Comment: @ab2 - You're not looking at the correct image.

Comment: Just to clarify, the brown part is not a separate piece.  It's all one piece.  Clearly (to me, at least) it's meant for liquid, not body parts.  There's no cork now, but it makes sense that there used to be one.